# TypeError: Cannot read property 'sorting' of undefined - When retrieving data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've built a web service where I can retrieve data from MongoDB to my table.
Locally, in my environment, the web service is working properly and display the data but when I am uploading it to my server (changing paths according to the structure of my server) I am facing with this kind of error:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'sorting' of undefined"
And the data is not displayed correctly in the table. From the console log, I can see that I retrieve the data but it is not displayed.

What can be the problem of it? I will insert the JS (controller) section part.

JS:

```
   $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams
    ({
        page: 1,
        count: 10

    },  {
        counts:[],
        dataset: $scope.logs,
        total: $scope.logs.length,
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
            $scope.data = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.logs, params.orderBy()) : $scope.logs;
            $scope.data = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.data, params.filter()) : $scope.data;
            $scope.data = $scope.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
            console.log($scope.data);
            $defer.resolve($scope.data);
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="table-responsive">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="tableAdmin">
                        <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true" export-csv="csv">
                            <tr ng-repeat="log in $data| orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter : searchLogins">
                                <td data-title="'ID'" sortable="'_id'">
                                    {{log._id}}
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="'Data'" sortable="'logData'">
                                    {{log.logData}}
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="'Date'" sortable="'logDate'">
                                    {{log.logDate}}
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="'Handled'">
                                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="log.selected" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <toaster-container toaster-options="{'close-button':true, 'time-out':{ 'toast-warning': 2000, 'toast-error': 0 } }"></toaster-container>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found what caused this problem, I had a wrong path that called the min.css file and not the .css file.
Now everything working properly.